# AWS create an Internal Network Load Balancer: instructions are contradictory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

OK I'm trying to create an internal Network Load Balancer.

On the console, it says:

```
Mappings
Select at least two Availability Zones and one subnet per zone.
```

[image]

And at the same time it also says:

```
Your internal load balancer must have a private subnet.
```

[image]

I have created a new subnet (`NLB-subnet`, or `subnet subnet-084f41a2d64bd25ad`, as shown in the picture above) in my VPC, just for the NLB.

When you create a new subnet, you must choose the zone in which your subnet will reside. And you can only choose one in the AWS console. So I did, and I chose `ap-northeast-1a`.

However, when it asks me to `Select at least two Availability Zones and one subnet per zone.`, I am confused like a 2 year old:

I have selected the AZ `ap-northeast-1a` for the NLB mapping, and that's where my new subnet resides, no problem.

But then I have to select a second AZ???

The seconds AZ has no subnet just for the NLB, because you can only choose one AZ for the subnet!

What does it want me to do?

Do I have to create a new private subnet in every one of the 3 Availability Zones, just for the NLB?

what? why?

Comment: Yes, you need to create multiple subnets. This is because the NLB is multi-az, allowing the NLB to continue to work if one of the AZs goes down.

Comment: @jordanm  Thanks for clarify!  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to place your NLB in two AZs, if you don't want. NLB works fine in a single AZ as well. Only for ALB it is required to have two AZs. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html#availability-zones):

> You **enable one** or more Availability Zones for your load balancer when you create it. If you enable multiple Availability Zones for your load balancer, this increases the fault tolerance of your applications.

Comment: Thank you! For testing I'll go with just one AZ. For production I will practice multi-AZs. As @jordamn pointed out, this allows the NLB to continue to work if one of the AZs goes down.